# WHM mod_rewrite mod_userdir

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, whm

I am facing a similar problem to

[Problems with mod_rewrite and mod_userdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661747/problems-with-mod-rewrite-and-mod-userdir)

But with WHM and I do not know the best way to start.

mod_rewrite goes to /usr/local/apache/htdocs/ when it should go to the user's userdir file at /home/*user*/public_html. The exact error is

```
File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.php, referer: http://<my ip>/~*user*/default.php
```

I thought about modifying httpd.conf but saw a lot of errors saying re-configuring WHM will erase modifications.

I also looked through the WHM docs and saw the open_basedir tweak: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_32/WHMDocs/TweakPhp

I thought I would ask first to avoid random troubleshooting as I have live sites on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my .htaccess, I had

```
RewriteBase /
```

I changed it to

```
RewriteBase /~<user>/
```

Example:

```
RewriteBase /~myusername/
```

and now it's working.